# How can i get the product version of InstallShield Project from my main project in C#

Tags: c#, installshield

In my soltuion VS, I have an project in C# and an InstallShield project.

I would like get the product Version of InstallShield :

[image]

But from my C# project like this :

```
string Version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

But it's the Assembly version and not product version of installshield.

Can use new reference COM : **InstallShield 22 Automation Interface**

with this code

```
var ISObject = new ISWiAuto22.ISWiProject();
ISObject.OpenProject(@strPath);
var version = ISObject.ProductVersion;
```

But with a InstallShield Limtied Edition we can't do this. For use *OpenProject*, the project file have to be .ism and mine is .isl, so i get an error : * This project was created using a previous version of InstallShield Developer, InstallShield - Windows Installer or InstallShield Express.*

Comment: are you trying to do this during the build or after you are installed and the product is running?

Answer (score 1):

You can use COM-interface of InstallShield to parsing IS project file.

VBS example:

```
Public Sub UpdateInstallerProductCode(strPath, strProductCode)
Dim objISWiProject

' Load InstallShield project
Set objISWiProject = CreateObject("ISWiAuto19.ISWiProject")
objISWiProject.OpenProject strPath

' Set new product code
objISWiProject.ProductCode = "{" & strProductCode & "}"

' Save and close InstallShield project
objISWiProject.SaveProject
objISWiProject.CloseProject
Set objISWiProject = Nothing
End Sub
```

I hate VB/S :))

Comment: Its not working, I let you look at my post at the top :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I was careless. Yes, on my computer I even cannot create new ISWiAuto22.ISWiProject(); , I have COM exception at once. Command line is absent in LE version. I would suggest to parse ISL file manually, if you need to get product version only, it's not so complicated.

Comment: Depending on whether the project is saved in Binary or XML format you can use MSI API to query the ISM (ISM is MSI backwards.. it's just an MSI database)  or  XPath to query the XML  (DTD format).